# How to hide elements when user is coming from a URL

Tags: wordpress, web

im new to website coding. I am trying to hide a div/element when user is coming from only some url.

For example

Hide id 123 when the user has come from google.com.

Can this be done?

Comment: Since you're using WP/PHP and you actually need some sort of persistence: look into `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, read it and store it somewhere (session is fine) and pass the decision (to hide or not to hide) to the frontend. Just don't do something critical based on `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` because it's not reliable and can tampered with.

Comment: It would be great if you provide the URL and div ID so, we will provide code for the same.

Comment: I want to hide a element internally only when user is coming from www.example.com/page1 to www.example/page2 then hide id123